# Make a spawner for enemies in OpenGL 2D

Tags: c++, 2d, game-development, glm-math

I have a project called Survival Shooter where I have to make a spawner for the enemies.
I dont know how to make multiple enemies spawn from random positions or like from one position but after 5 seconds for example.

```
void Tema1::SpawnEnemy(glm::mat3 visMatrix, float deltaTime, float* posX, float* posY, float speed)
{

enemyAngle = atan2(translateX - *posX, translateY - *posY);
*posX += speed * sin(enemyAngle) * deltaTime;
*posY += speed * cos(enemyAngle) * deltaTime;

//Body
modelMatrix = visMatrix;
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(*posX, *posY);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Scale(1, 1);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(enemyAngle);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-50, -50);
RenderMesh2D(meshes["border"], shaders["VertexColor"], modelMatrix);

//Eye1
modelMatrix = visMatrix;
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(*posX, *posY);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Scale(0.25f, 0.25f);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(enemyAngle);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(150, 200);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(0);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-50, -50);
RenderMesh2D(meshes["square2"], shaders["VertexColor"], modelMatrix);

//Eye2
modelMatrix = visMatrix;
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(*posX, *posY);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Scale(0.25f, 0.25f);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(enemyAngle);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-150, 200);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(0);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-50, -50);
RenderMesh2D(meshes["square2"], shaders["VertexColor"], modelMatrix);

}
```

This is the method that I call when I want to draw a new enemy and I call it in the Update method.

The question is, how do I draw a new enemy after an amount of time without destroying the current enemies that I have in the scene?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly represent enemies in your game state:

```
struct Enemy {
  glm::vec2 pos;
  glm::vec2 speed;
  ...
  void update(float deltaTime); // Update position and/or speed
  void draw(); // Actually draw
};

std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
```

Spawning an enemy is then simply a matter of creating a new `Enemy` object and adding it to the vector.
Destroying an enemy is a matter of removing an `Enemy` object from the vector. Beware of the usual issues with removing items from a vector you are iterating over though.

Your game loop should first call `update(deltaTime)` on all objects and then `draw()` them.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to pick a way to store your enemies. Since you are working in `C++`, I'd recommend you to define a base class `entity` for the players, items, entities and anything else that will be rendered. It will define a single function: `update(float delta)`, where delta is the time it took us to render the previous frame. After that, you can make a class `movableEntity`, inheriting `entity`, that can move (is controllable, either by a player or by an AI). The class will define a few functions: `jump`, `moveBack`, `moveForward`, `attack`, etc... It will define two fields, as well: `float x` and `float y` It really depends on what your enemies will be able to do. Now, we define a class for our enemy, which should be called `enemyEntity`, and it will inherit `movableEntity`.

Now, you need to have a list of all entities present in the world. You will iterate trough it and will call `render(delta)` on each one of them. For the enemies, you should implement an AI, that uses the controller to control the enemy (it is recommended that the `controllableEntity` class defines the moving functions so they have some sort of a cooldown). It should be included in the update funcion of the enemy. Preferably, you could write the enemy AI so that you just specify a target.

Here's an example enemy AI for a 2D game that is viewed from the side (like most platformers):

```cpp
void update(float delta) {
    float distanceX = x - target->x;

    if (distanceX > 1) {
        moveLeft();
    }
    else if (distanceX < -1) {
        moveRight();
    }
    else {
        attack();
    }
}
```

Of course, this is a very basic AI, that doesn't take into account any obstacles on its way, but the `movableEntity` class ensures that the player can do as much as the entity can. If you need any help, write in the comments